# How to determine if result of process substitution is a file path

Tags: bash, shell, test, file-descriptors, read

If I do this:

```
echo <(cat)
```

I get:

```
/dev/fd/63
```

so say at the command line I have:

```
myapp -f <(cat)
```

when I run it I get this error:

> You need to pass a file after the -f flag. The resolved file path was:
>   '/dev/fd/63'. This path did not appear to exist on the filesystem.

How can I determine if the result of the process substitution is an actual file (for validation purposes)?  Here is my bash code which generated the error:

```
  if [[ -L "$file_path" ]]; then
     file_path="$(readlink "$file_path")";
  fi

  if [[ ! -f "$file_path" ]]; then
    echo "You need to pass a file after the -f flag. The resolved file path was: '$file_path'. This path did not appear to exist on the filesystem".;
    return 1;
  fi
```

if I get rid of my validation, code, I get this:

> Could not open the following file for reading: /dev/fd/63 EBADF: bad
>   file descriptor, open '/dev/fd/63'

The node.js code I am using to read from the path is:

```
const fd = fs.openSync(file_path, 'r');
fs.read(fd, ...);
```

Comment: `[ -f file ]` tests if `file` is a __regular__ file, and the file created by a process substitution is a __pipe__, not a regular file. Also, on Linux, the target of a `/dev/fd/n` -> `/proc/self/fd/n` "symlink" is some informative string like `type:[inum]`, not a path for pipes, sockets, etc.

Comment: so much for everything is a file lulz..anyway I just want to be able to read from `/dev/fd/x`, is there some way to do that?

Comment: maybe you should post a complete example; `node -e 'fs=require("fs"); fs.openSync(process.argv[1], "r")' <(cat /dev/null)` works for me.

Comment: But simply `cat <(cat)` will not work from console, because the `cat` inside the process substitution may run in a different process group than the foreground one, and cannot read from the tty.

Comment: Yeah I was on MacOS, let me try on Ubuntu

Comment: Yeah works on ubuntu but not macos

Comment: I don't have a MacOS system. But someone else may have, so post a complete reproducible testcase. FWIW, on BSD, `/dev/fd/N` are character special files (they aren't regular files, either). And on FreeBSD you should mount [`fdescfs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdescfs&sektion=5&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) if you want to access filedescs > 2 via `/dev/fd/N`.

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine, in Bash, whether a string value is a path on your current system, use `[[ -e "$path" ]]`. This checks whether the path *exists,* and doesn't make any assumptions about the type of file it points to.

Comment: this definitely helps, thanks